# How to convert DataSet to XML and back to DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

I have written below code to generate XML from DataSet and then back to same DataSet. But my resultant DataSet is always empty.

the test method looks like this -

```
[Test]
public void XmlToDataSetTest()
{
    var dataSetExpected = GenerateDataSet();
    var xmlString = GetXml(dataSetExpected);
    var dataSetActual = GetDataSet(xmlString); //dataSetActual is always empty, no DataTables inside
    //Assert
 }

private DataSet GenerateDataSet()
{
    var dataSet = new DataSet("DataSetSample");

    for (int dt = 0; dt < 2; dt++)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable($"Table{dt}");

        for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn($"Column{c}"));
        }

        for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++)
        {
            var workRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++)
            {
                workRow[r] = $"Column{c} - Row{r}";
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(workRow);
        }

        dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
    }

    return dataSet;
}

public DataSet GetDataSet(string xml)
{
    var dataSet = new DataSet();
    var xmlSR = new StringReader(xml);
    dataSet.ReadXml(xmlSR, XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema);
    return dataSet;
}

public string GetXml(DataSet dataSet)
{
    return dataSet.GetXml();
}
```

My expectation is `dataSetActual` should be exactly same as  `dataSetExpected`. But for some reason `dataSetActual` is always empty. I understand this is not supposed to be that tricky. There might be something very trivial that i am missing.

Could anyone please help me solve this issue?

**Edit:**

I modified `GetDataSet` to use `WriteXml` as per @jgw's suggestion but still the same issue. `dataSetActual` is still blank in test method -

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string xml)
        {
            var dataSet = new DataSet();
            var xmlStringWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder(xml));
            dataSet.WriteXml(xmlStringWriter, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            return dataSet;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the GetXml function will return a simple xml string that isn't really intended to be put back into DataSet.  The schema can be inferred from the existing XML but in practice there is an easier way.

Use the WriteXml method instead and you can work with the WriteXmlMode to see if you want just the data, the schema, or both.

See the remarks in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.writexml?view=netcore-3.1

Sure, remember that the "WriteXml" is taking the dataset and creating the XML and the "ReadXml" is converting an xml stream back to a dataset.  You can play with the XmlWriteMode and XmlReadMode to keep the schema depending on your circumstances.  Here's some working code:

```
public string GetXml(DataSet dataSet)
{
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        dataSet.WriteXml(memStream);
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memStream.ToArray());
    }
}

public DataSet ToDataSet(string xml)
{
    var byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(byteData))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(memStream);  
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems odd that it just silently fails and result in an empty `DataSet`, because you could write `(new DataSet()).ReadXml(new StringReader("<foo></foo>"));` and nothing happens, no exception at all

Comment: @kgw - i changed the code to use WriteXML method, but i still have the same issue. Please see the edits. Do you mind providing a sample code to show how this can be done?

Comment: @user979189 If this worked for you and helped you, it would be very helpful to me if you would credit me with the answer.